# Getting Two Answers From a Non-Linear Equation On Python

Tags: python, math

I wrote a code that is supposed to return all solutions to a non-linear systems of equations  using Python. The program only gives one of the two solutions for a system of non-linear equations that is supposed to provide two solutions. I know that the system provides two solutions, as I have algebraically checked it myself, and with other equation solving tools on the internet.

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

#define system of equations here:
#w[0] = x, w[1] = y, w[2] = z
#Put all equations in terms of 0 = expression, and write F[n] = expression
def nonlinearEquation(w):    
    F=np.zeros(3)
    F[0] = (w[0]-mx)**2+(w[1]-my)**2+(w[2]-mz)**2-l
    F[1] = angle*(w[0]-mx) - (w[1]-my)
    F[2] = w[0]**2 + w[1]**2 - w[2]
    return F

initialGuess = np.random.rand(3)

#Get all solution info:
solutionInfo = [None] * 6  # Initialize a list to store the solutions

for i in range(6):
    angle = angleIncrement * i
    angle = math.tan(math.radians(angle))
    solutionInfo[i] = fsolve(nonlinearEquation, initialGuess, full_output=1)

# Extract Solution
for i in range(6):
    
    solutionOne = solutionInfo[i][0] 
    print("(" + str(round(solutionOne[0], 4)) + ", " + str(round(solutionOne[1], 6)) + ", " + str(round(solutionOne[2], 4)) + ")")
```

You can define the variables used in the equation, such as mx, my, mz, l, etc. Upon running, it provides just one solution per system. I may appear as six, because I repeat the system six times with some minor variation of one of the variables. However, while the first three are unique solutions, the last three are just the first three. All solutions are supposed to be different...

Please let me know what changes I need to make,

thanks so much.